# Communication between two classes that extend another one

Tags: java

I need to pass a value between classes that inherit another class.

My super class looks like this

```
class A {
  int distance;

  public A(int distance) {
     this.distance = distance;
  }

  public void setDistance(int distance) {
     this.distance = distance;
  }

  public int getDistance() {
     return distance;
  }
}
```

The child class B sets a value to the distance variable.

```
class B extends A {
  public B(int distance) {
     super(distance);
  }

  // some code to change the distance
}
```

When I try to get that value in child class C, it gives me 0 (default for int).

```
class C extends A {
  public C(int distance) {
     super(distance);
  }

  // some code to get the distance
}
```

I think the reason behind it is related to class B and class C creating new objects for class A, therefore they're using they're indivual class A, right?
How can I get this to work?

Comment: how are you trying to get that value? In your C class, I see no code linking to B.

Comment: Make sure you actually passing the value to the constructor

Comment: Can you include a main method that uses the provided classes? If I had to guess I think you have done something we cannot see which makes this not work.

Comment: Even two instances of `A` would have different variables from each other, for each instance created. If you want multiple instances to share a single value, you need to have that value be `static`.

Comment: Just for your clarification: Every object A, B or C you create will have it's very own value for distance. Changing the distance in one object will not affect other objects. That's kind of the point of having different objects. Going by your problem description it kind of sounds like you expect all objects you create to share one value for distance.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy so I need to make the distance field static in class A?

Comment: @matt this is the simplification of what I'm trying to figure out, the whole program is a multi threading program that in its whole controls a robot with the producer-consumer problem.

Comment: The way this site works, you try to reduce your problem down to the simplest you can and reproduce the output. If you look at the current "answer" you could get an idea of how simple of a main class you can use. It sounds like you want to use 'distance' as a static value. In that case you probably shouldn't be changing it in the constructor unless you have a special reason.

Comment: why would you add "some code to get the distance"? You already inherit those methods from A

Comment: You cannot share state between different objects this way. There are design patterns that could address this problem, but for a simple solution you could replace `inheritance` with `composition`: instead of having classes B and C extending A, add A as a member (field) to each B and C (create A in main and pass it to both B and C constructors). Let me know if this is what you really need and if you need me to post is as an answer with code example.

Answer (score 0):

The child classes inherit attributes/variables and functions/methods of the superclass. You do not need to add methods for getting the distance in the child classes.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        B b = new B(200);
        C c = new C(300);
        System.out.println(b.getDistance());  // 200
        System.out.println(c.getDistance());  // 300
    }
}
```